# Копирование диапазонов таблицы с подстановкой условия

Tags: google-apps-script

Добрый день! 
Есть табличка, [Пример Таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZdcmZsdkOfaWCBzTiotdTQEEGQIvUI2t5eNptupeR0/edit#gid=953837311) в которой происходит расчет по заданному условию  в ячейке C1. (выбирается из массива: `var znach = ["Значение1", "Значение2", "Значение3", "Значение4"]` и вставляется в ячейку C1),
затем диапазоны таблицы B3:D7, B15:D19,B27:D31 копируются на лист zzz02 и т.д. (на листе zzz02 для наглядности показано, как должны выглядеть скопированные данные после подстановки и копирования всех значений).
Пробовал вложенным циклом, но тогда получается что все копируется по последнему выбранному значению из списка.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно можно решить данную задачу.

Comment: В табличку не зайти, пишет нет прав

Comment: Извиняюсь, установил.

Comment: Уточню, у Вас скриптом вставляется в С1 значения из массива znach, а потом копируется на второй лист. И так цикл 4 раза?

Comment: Может приведете пример своего кода?

Comment: Да, из массива первое значение вставляется в C1, затем результат копируется и так 4 раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял Ваш вопрос, код будет примерно такой:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Лист1")
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Лист2")

  var znach = ["Значение1", "Значение2", "Значение3", "Значение4"]
  var col = 2
  for(var i = 0; i < znach.length; i++){
    sheet2.getRange("C1").setValue(znach[i])
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    sheet2.getRange("B3:D7").copyTo(sheet1.getRange(3, col, 5, 3), {contentsOnly:true})
    sheet2.getRange("B15:D19").copyTo(sheet1.getRange(9, col, 5, 3), {contentsOnly:true})
    sheet2.getRange("B27:D31").copyTo(sheet1.getRange(15, col, 5, 3), {contentsOnly:true})
    col+=3
  }
}
```

Comment: Точно, у меня i < znach.length; находился в отдельном цикле, поэтому копировалось неверно. Спасибо за помощь и что подтвердили мою догадку!